# Seleccionar filas con un fecha inferior a otra MySQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, date

Las tablas de las que se disponen en el ejercicio son:

**Master**

```
master_id |INT ----> PRIMARY KEY
name | VARCHAR ----> ALTERNATIVE KEY
curriculum_rev | DATE
```

**Subject**

```
subject_id | VARCHAR -----> PRIMARY KEY
name | VARCHAR
language | ENUM
description |VARCHAR
ECTS | INT
m_id | INT ----> FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES master_id
```

Pregunta: Se quiere conseguir una sentencia MySQL donde se muestre el nombre del master, asignaturas, creditos y lengua impartida de estas pero unicamente de las que no tienen descripción i la revisión del plan de estudios (curriculum_rev) del Master sea anterior a 2016.

Para ello, he realizado la siguiente sentencia:

```
select m.name,s.name,s.`language`,s.ECTS
from master m, subject s
where m.master_id=s.m_id AND description is null AND m.curriculum_date < 2016
```

Me da un error de sintaxis y supongo que es con el tratamiento de la fecha.Como puedo hacerlo? Gracias.

Comment: por favor date una vuelta por [ask] requerimos que muestres:  la estructura de la tabla involucrada y la consulta SQL que lleves al momento

Comment: Para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida, podrías compartir el código de lo que haz intentado para resolver el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Panri93. La funcion year() ayuda a mostrar solo el año de una determinada fecha. Con esa funcion puedes evaluar con el año 2016.

```
select  master.name, subject.name, ECTS, language
from    master, subject 
where   master.master_id = subject.m_id and 
        description is null and 
        year(curriculum_rev) < 2016
```